# tikz-qtree cannot display part of child nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

When I was creating a **large** tree using `tikz-qtree`, I found that part of child nodes cannot be displayed.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\renewcommand{\PreviewBorder}{1cm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  textwidth = 80em
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\def\pgfname{\textsc{pgf}}
\def\tikzname{Ti\emph{k}Z}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=right, sibling distance=4ex]

\tikzstyle{level 1} = [level distance= 20em]
\tikzstyle{level 2} = [level distance= 28em]
\tikzstyle{level 3} = [level distance= 30em]
\tikzstyle{edge from parent} = [draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzchildnode.west) -- ++(-2em,0) |- (\tikzparentnode.east)}]
% \tikzstyle{edge from parent} = [draw, edge from parent fork right]
\tikzstyle{nd0} = [draw=black, minimum width=8em, text width=10em, align=center]
\tikzstyle{nd1} = [draw=black, minimum width=8em, text width=20em, align=center]
\tikzstyle{nd2} = [draw=black, minimum width=8em, text width=26em, align=left]

\tikzstyle{every tree node} = [fill=red!30, font=\bfseries]
\tikzstyle{done}  = [fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{doing} = [fill=cyan!30]
\tikzstyle{not}   = [fill=red!30]

\Tree 
% [ .\node [nd0, doing] {\tikzname\ \& PGF \\ \pgfversion\ \\ 中文手册};
[ .\node [nd0, doing] {\tikzname\ \& PGF \\ \pgfversion};
    [ . \node [nd1, doing] {Introduction};
        [ . \node [nd2, done] {The Layers Below \tikzname}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2, doing] {Comparison with Other Graphics Packages}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2, not] {Utility Packages}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2, not] {How to Read This Manual}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2, not] {Authors and Acknowledgements}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2, not] {Getting Help}; ]
    ]
    [ . \node [nd1] {Tutorials and Guidelines};
        [ . \node [nd2] {Tutorial: A Picture for Karl's Students}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Tutorial: A Petri-Net for Hagen}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Tutorial: Euclid's Amber Version of the Elements}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Tutorial: Diagrams as Simple Graphs}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Tutorial: A Lecture Map for Johannes}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Tutorial: Guidelines on Graphics}; ]
    ]
    [ . \node [nd1] {Installation and Configurations}; 
        [ . \node [nd2] {Installation}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Licenses and Copyright}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Supported Formats}; ]
    ]
    [ . \node [nd1] {Ti\emph{k}Z ist \emph{kein} Zeichenprogramm};
        [ . \node [nd2] {Design Principles}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Hierarchical Structures: \\ Package, Environments, Scopes, and Styles}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Specifying Coordinates}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Syntax for Path Specifications}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Actions on Paths}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Arrows}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Nodes and Edges}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Pics: Small Pictures on Paths}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Specifying Graphs}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Matrices and Alignment}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Making Trees Grow}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Plots of Functions}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Transparency}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Decorated Paths}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Transformations}; ]
    ]
    [ . \node [nd1] {Graph Drawing};
        [ . \node [nd2] {Introduction to Algorithmic Graph Drawing}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Using Graph Drawing in \tikzname}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Using Graph Drawing in PGF}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Graph Drawing Layouts: Trees}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Graph Drawing Algorithms: Layered Layouts}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Graph Drawing Algorithms: Force-Based Methods}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Graph Drawing Algorithms: Circular Layouts}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Graph Drawing Layouts: Phylogenetic Trees}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Graph Drawing Algorithms: Edge Routing}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {The Algorithm Layer}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Writing Graph Drawing Algorithms in C}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {The Display Layer}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {The Binding Layer}; ]
    ]
    [ . \node [nd1] {Libraries};
        [ . \node [nd2] {Angle Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Arrow Tip Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Automata Drawing Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Babel Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Background Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Calc Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Calendar Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Chains}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Circuit Libraries}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Decoration Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Entity-Relationship Diagram Drawing Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Externalization Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Fading Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Fitting Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Fixed Point Arithmetic Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Floating Point Unit Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Lindenmayer System Drawing Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Math Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Matrix Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Mindmap Drawing Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Paper Folding Diagrams Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Pattern Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Petri-Net Drawing Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Plot Handler Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Plot Mark Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Profiler Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Shadings Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Shadows Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Shape Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Spy Library: Magnifying Parts of Pictures}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {SVG-Path Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {To Path Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Through Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Tree Library}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Turtle Graphics Library}; ]
    ]
    [ . \node [nd1] {Data Visualization}; 
        [ . \node [nd2] {Introduction to Data Visualization}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Creating Data Visualizations}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Providing Data for a Data Visualization}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Axes}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Visualizers}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Style Sheets and Legends}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Polar Axes}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {The Data Visualization Backend}; ]
    ]
    [ . \node [nd1] {Utilities}; 
        [ . \node [nd2] {Key Management}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Date and Calendar Utility Macros}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Page Management}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Extended Color Support}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Parser Module}; ]
    ]
    [ . \node [nd1] {Mathematical and Objected Engines}; 
        [ . \node [nd2] {Design Principles}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Mathematical Expressions}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Additional Mathematical Commands}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Customizing the Mathematical Engine}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Number Printing}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Object-Oriented Programming}; ]
    ]
    [ . \node [nd1] {The Basic Layer};
        [ . \node [nd2] {Design Principles}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Hierarchical Structures: \\ Package, Environments, Scopes, and Text}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Specifying Coordinates}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Constructing Paths}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Decorations}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Using Paths}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Defining New Arrow Tip Kinds}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Nodes and Shapes}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Matrices}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Coordinate, Canvas, and Nonlinear Transformations}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Patterns}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Declaring and Using Images}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Externalizing Graphics}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Creating Plots}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Layered Graphics}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Shadings}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Transparency}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Adding libraries to PGF: temporary registers}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Quick Commands}; ]
    ]
    [ . \node [nd1] {The System Layer};
        [ . \node [nd2] {Design of the System Layer}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {Commands of the System Layer}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {The Soft Path Subsystem}; ]
        [ . \node [nd2] {The Protocol Subsystem}; ]
    ]
    [ . \node [nd1, done] {References and Index}; ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

The compile command is `latexmk -pv -xelatex test.tex`

Note that in the output, a number of childs of the 'Libraries' do not display. And with more tests I find that the number of diplayed childs of current parent is dependent to the number of other parents' childs and the order of the parent nodes. This is really strange.

**I guess that this problem might be related to some internal number limits somewhere.**

[image]

Zoom in to see the details more clearly:

[image]

Comment: It seems that at most 24 entries are accepted with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Is there any way to break this limit in XeLaTeX, say, by adding some commands?

Comment: Off-topic: note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: @egreg Why do you think it is the number of entries? Or maybe I mean, which entries?

Comment: It has something to do, I think, with the total size when compiling with XeTeX. If you put `\tiny` before the tree, all of the nodes appear.

Comment: @cfr That's a nice find, but I can't see what can cause the issue.

Comment: @egreg Oh, no. ...

Comment: @cfr Yes, and must not be larger than `tiny` in this case. Even the `small` or `footnotesize` cannot work too...

Comment: Would be nice to know **why**, though, as @egreg says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `\tiny` before the tree, all the nodes appear. Another option, as [your answer notes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439215/), is to switch from XeTeX to pdfTeX as engine.

If you need to use XeTeX and you do not want to reduce the size of the font, a third option is `forest`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\newcommand\pgfname{\textsc{pgf}}
\newcommand\tikzname{Ti\emph{k}Z}
\tikzset{
  nd0/.style={draw=black, minimum width=8em, text width=10em, align=center},
  nd1/.style={draw=black, minimum width=8em, text width=20em, align=center},
  nd2/.style={draw=black, minimum width=8em, text width=26em, align=left},
  every tree node/.style={fill=red!30, font=\bfseries},
  done/.style={fill=green!30},
  doing/.style={fill=cyan!30},
  not/.style={fill=red!30},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={every tree node, folder, grow'=0}
  [\tikzname\ \& PGF\\\pgfversion, nd0, doing
    [Introduction, nd1, doing
        [The Layers Below \tikzname, nd2, done]
        [Comparison with Other Graphics Packages, nd2, doing]
        [Utility Packages, nd2, not]
        [How to Read This Manual, nd2, not]
        [Authors and Acknowledgements, nd2, not]
        [Getting Help, nd2, not]
    ]
    [Tutorials and Guidelines, nd1
        [Tutorial: A Picture for Karl's Students, nd2]
        [Tutorial: A Petri-Net for Hagen, nd2]
        [Tutorial: Euclid's Amber Version of the Elements, nd2]
        [Tutorial: Diagrams as Simple Graphs, nd2]
        [Tutorial: A Lecture Map for Johannes, nd2]
        [Tutorial: Guidelines on Graphics, nd2]
    ]
    [Installation and Configurations, nd1
        [Installation, nd2]
        [Licenses and Copyright, nd2]
        [Supported Formats, nd2]
    ]
    [Ti\emph{k}Z ist \emph{kein} Zeichenprogramm, nd1
        [Design Principles, nd2]
        [Hierarchical Structures:\\{Package, Environments, Scopes, and Styles}, nd2]
        [Specifying Coordinates, nd2]
        [Syntax for Path Specifications, nd2]
        [Actions on Paths, nd2]
        [Arrows, nd2]
        [Nodes and Edges, nd2]
        [Pics: Small Pictures on Paths, nd2]
        [Specifying Graphs, nd2]
        [Matrices and Alignment, nd2]
        [Making Trees Grow, nd2]
        [Plots of Functions, nd2]
        [Transparency, nd2]
        [Decorated Paths, nd2]
        [Transformations, nd2]
    ]
    [Graph Drawing, nd1
        [Introduction to Algorithmic Graph Drawing, nd2]
        [Using Graph Drawing in \tikzname, nd2]
        [Using Graph Drawing in PGF, nd2]
        [Graph Drawing Layouts: Trees, nd2]
        [Graph Drawing Algorithms: Layered Layouts, nd2]
        [Graph Drawing Algorithms: Force-Based Methods, nd2]
        [Graph Drawing Algorithms: Circular Layouts, nd2]
        [Graph Drawing Layouts: Phylogenetic Trees, nd2]
        [Graph Drawing Algorithms: Edge Routing, nd2]
        [The Algorithm Layer, nd2]
        [Writing Graph Drawing Algorithms in C, nd2]
        [The Display Layer, nd2]
        [The Binding Layer, nd2]
    ]
    [Libraries, nd1
        [Angle Library, nd2]
        [Arrow Tip Library, nd2]
        [Automata Drawing Library, nd2]
        [Babel Library, nd2]
        [Background Library, nd2]
        [Calc Library, nd2]
        [Calendar Library, nd2]
        [Chains, nd2]
        [Circuit Libraries, nd2]
        [Decoration Library, nd2]
        [Entity-Relationship Diagram Drawing Library, nd2]
        [Externalization Library, nd2]
        [Fading Library, nd2]
        [Fitting Library, nd2]
        [Fixed Point Arithmetic Library, nd2]
        [Floating Point Unit Library, nd2]
        [Lindenmayer System Drawing Library, nd2]
        [Math Library, nd2]
        [Matrix Library, nd2]
        [Mindmap Drawing Library, nd2]
        [Paper Folding Diagrams Library, nd2]
        [Pattern Library, nd2]
        [Petri-Net Drawing Library, nd2]
        [Plot Handler Library, nd2]
        [Plot Mark Library, nd2]
        [Profiler Library, nd2]
        [Shadings Library, nd2]
        [Shadows Library, nd2]
        [Shape Library, nd2]
        [Spy Library: Magnifying Parts of Pictures, nd2]
        [SVG-Path Library, nd2]
        [To Path Library, nd2]
        [Through Library, nd2]
        [Tree Library, nd2]
        [Turtle Graphics Library, nd2]
    ]
    [Data Visualization, nd1
        [Introduction to Data Visualization, nd2]
        [Creating Data Visualizations, nd2]
        [Providing Data for a Data Visualization, nd2]
        [Axes, nd2]
        [Visualizers, nd2]
        [Style Sheets and Legends, nd2]
        [Polar Axes, nd2]
        [The Data Visualization Backend, nd2]
    ]
    [Utilities, nd1
        [Key Management, nd2]
        [Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement, nd2]
        [Date and Calendar Utility Macros, nd2]
        [Page Management, nd2]
        [Extended Color Support, nd2]
        [Parser Module, nd2]
    ]
    [Mathematical and Objected Engines, nd1
        [Design Principles, nd2]
        [Mathematical Expressions, nd2]
        [Additional Mathematical Commands, nd2]
        [Customizing the Mathematical Engine, nd2]
        [Number Printing, nd2]
        [Object-Oriented Programming, nd2]
    ]
    [The Basic Layer, nd1
        [Design Principles, nd2]
        [Hierarchical Structures:\\{Package, Environments, Scopes, and Text}, nd2]
        [Specifying Coordinates, nd2]
        [Constructing Paths, nd2]
        [Decorations, nd2]
        [Using Paths, nd2]
        [Defining New Arrow Tip Kinds, nd2]
        [Nodes and Shapes, nd2]
        [Matrices, nd2]
        [{Coordinate, Canvas, and Nonlinear Transformations}, nd2]
        [Patterns, nd2]
        [Declaring and Using Images, nd2]
        [Externalizing Graphics, nd2]
        [Creating Plots, nd2]
        [Layered Graphics, nd2]
        [Shadings, nd2]
        [Transparency, nd2]
        [Adding libraries to PGF: temporary registers, nd2]
        [Quick Commands, nd2]
    ]
    [The System Layer, nd1
        [Design of the System Layer, nd2]
        [Commands of the System Layer, nd2]
        [The Soft Path Subsystem, nd2]
        [The Protocol Subsystem, nd2]
    ]
    [References and Index, nd1, done]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest version compiled with XeLaTeX]

Comment: Both `tiny` and `forest` work perfectly! I recommend using the `forest` one. I have considered using `forest`, but I spent much time seeking ways to draw `tikz` nodes beside the tree, for example, some legends or notes, and it seems hard to do that in `forest` environment. Maybe I need to put this to a new question...

Comment: @Isimovvv I think that's a new question, preferably with a smaller example as this takes a while to crunch!

Answer (score 2):

I finally find one solution to this problem by trial and error.

Replacing the compile command

`latexmk -pv -xelatex test.tex`

to

`latexmk -pv -pdf test.tex`

However, I still do not know why this works.

Comment: Now you are not using XeTeX but pdfTeX, so obviously it is not subject to limits specific to XeTeX.